# Find all occurrences of a variable time stamp structure in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Given that a time stamp can have several constructions i.e.

- HH:MM:SS
- H:MM:SS
- MMM:SS
- MM:SS
- M:SS

Currently I'm using `re.findall()` with the `|` alternates operator.

Is there a more efficient method of finding all of the above possible type of time stamps
in a string than the following:

```
aString = "the cat  (01:03)  sat on [01:01:01] the ( 9:13 )mat( 1:10:11)."
bString = "the cat 01:14:23.447 sat on the mat"
cString = "the cat 01:14:23.447 --> 01:17:10.239 sat on the mat"
dString = "the cat 323:14 sat on the mat"


v = re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{3}:\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}',aString)
x = re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{3}:\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}',bString)
y = re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{3}:\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}',cString)
z = re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{3}:\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}|\d:\d{2}',dString)

v
['01:03', '01:01:01', '9:13', '1:10:11']
x
['01:14:23']
y
['01:14:23', '01:17:10']
z
['323:14']
```

Note: I don't care about milliseconds if they are included in the time stamp.

Comment: If you're matching but not validating at the same time, `\d+:\d+(?::\d+)?` would be enough. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/DY6dsF/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
aString = "the cat  (01:03)  sat on [01:01:01] the ( 9:13 )mat( 1:10:11)."
bString = "the cat 01:14:23.447 sat on the mat"
cString = "the cat 01:14:23.447 --> 01:17:10.239 sat on the mat"
dString = "the cat 323:14 sat on the mat"

v = re.findall('\d{1,3}(?::\d{2}){1,2}', aString)
x = re.findall('\d{1,3}(?::\d{2}){1,2}', bString)
y = re.findall('\d{1,3}(?::\d{2}){1,2}', cString)
z = re.findall('\d{1,3}(?::\d{2}){1,2}', dString)

print(v, x, y, z, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['01:03', '01:01:01', '9:13', '1:10:11']
['01:14:23']
['01:14:23', '01:17:10']
['323:14']
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/AW4spZ/1/)

Explanation:

- `\d{1,3}` match at least 1 and at most 3 digits
- `(?:` start non-capturing group

  - `:\d{2}` match a colon and 2 digits
- `)` end group
- `{1,2}` match the preceding group at least 1 and at most 2 times

Comment: Works well, I need to test this and revo's suggestion to see which produces fewer false positives on text which includes various options with the colon character, regards.

Comment: Revo' solution will work for all the cases you've shown here. Only thing is, that regex will match strings with any number of digits, for example, patterns like `ddddd:d:dddddddd` or anything like this. In my solution, you can change the values of `{1,3}` to match the number of digits as per your needs. Otherwise, both the solutions are same.

Answer (score 1):

If you're matching but not validating at the same time, below regex would be enough:

```
\d+:\d+(?::\d+)?
```

Breakdown:

- `\d+:\d+` Match a digit(s) colon digit(s) string
- `(?:` Start of non-captruing group

  - `:\d+` Match colon digit(s)
- `)?` End of NCG, optional

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/DY6dsF/1)